# Scheduled jenkins build doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, cron

I need to set up a build job to start on Monday-Friday every day at 7 am. I tried different cron expressions like:

```
0 7 * * 1-5
H 7 * * 1-5
00 07 * * 1-5
H 07 * * 1-5
```

The job just won't start. It builds fine when I start it manually, it somehow works if I set it to 8 am instead of 7 am. I have another job that runs at 9 pm and it works fine.
Jenkins logs only contain entries about successful/failed builds, nothing on the non-started jobs. I've seen people asking similar questions, but they all had the issue resolve itself, which isn't happening for me. I've already checked the timezone settings.

Is this some sort of a Jenkins bug (I am working with version 1.583)? Do I need to make a cron job on the server itself that will trigger builds using Jenkins CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Jenkins and the server that it's own is not down at 7am for some kind of maintenance/backup?

Comment: Nope. Jenkins is installed on a cloud vm and I get all notifications if any machine goes down for maintenance.